# Corebluetooth state preservation willRestoreState

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

This application implements central manager state preservation and restoration. (IOS 7.1)

When the application is terminated by the system (e.i memory low ) the core bluetooth continues monitoring the peripheral's events on the application behalf, so the peripheral continues connected.

Now, if the peripheral disconnect (e.i. our of range ) the application is relaunched into background and **willRestoreState** is called but **didDisconnectPeripheral** is never called, but if the application is brought back to foreground by the user, then **didDisconnectPeripheral** is called.

This application **must** process **didDisconnectPeripheral** event after the state restoration while it is still in background.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Is the peripheral listed under the key CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey ? If it is not listed, you can assume that the link has been terminated. And if it is listed, and the connectionState property of the CBPeripheral says that the peripheral is not connected, you can also assume that the link has been terminated.

Comment: @Etan I guess your reasoning is correct but the calling of the `didDisconnectPeripheral` when foregrounded again is a discrepancy if all your asumptions are considered. I'm not saying it's impossible to handle, though.

Comment: If you set the background-key in Info.plist you will get the didDisconnectPeripheral even if you are backgrounded (as long as you are not using the main queue - as this queue is suspended in background). If your app gets killed you won't get the didDisconnectPeripheral callback, but instead you will get relaunched into background and state will be passed via the willRestoreState dictionary. These are different modes.

Comment: As I mentioned at the beginning: the app implements central manager state preservation and restoration so: CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey and background-key in Info.plist are setup as per Apple documentation. If the app is killed, CB will launched the app into background after a bluetooth event and willRestoreState is the first delegate called for restoration purposes, after restoration, the bluetooth event that caused the application to be launched into background in first place is sent to the application.

Comment: any work around for this? i am having the same scenario